# How could I update an input field live?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to update an input field in real-time. I don't know how else to put it.

I'm making a sort-of shell in Python 3.11, and I have the current working directory as the input field.
This is what I have right now:

```
cwd0=os.getcwd()

while True:
  command_line=input(f"{cwd0}! ")
```

After changing directories with `os.chdir`, the input field doesn't change along with it.

Really hope someone can help with this! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the function call in the prompt, not a variable.

```
command_line=input(f"{os.getcwd()}! ")
```

Or update the variable whenever you call `os.chdir()`. Variables are not automatically updated when the expression they were assigned from changes.